# Giving Range to the SQL Column

Tags: sql, select, random, weighted

I have SQL table in which I have column and Probability . I want to select one row from it with randomly but I want to give more chances to the more waighted probability. I can do this by

```
    Order By abs(checksum(newid()))
```

But the difference between Probabilities are too much so it gives more chance to highest probability.Like After picking 74 times that value it pick up another value for once than again around 74 times.I want to reduce this .Like I want 3-4 times to it and than others and all. I am thinking to give Range to the Probabilies.Its Like

```
    Row[i] = Row[i-1]+Row[i]
```

How can I do this .Do I need to create function?Is there any there any other way to achieve this.I am neewby.Any help will be appriciated.Thank You

**EDIT:**
I have solution of my problem . I have one question .
if I have table as follows.

```
    Column1   Column2
     1         50
     2         30
     3         20
```

can i get?

```
    Column1   Column2  Column3
     1         50       50
     2         30       80
     3         20       100
```

Each time I want to add value with existing one.Is there any Way?

**UPDATE:**
 Finally get the solution after 3 hours,I just take square root of my probailities that way I can narrow the difference bw them .It is like I add column with

```
    sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(Probability)))....:-)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want column3 to be the sum of all the other (previous) entries and the (current) value in column 2?  That's not a bad idea.  But you're wondering how to generate it? There'd be several ways, but I'm not sure what would be the best.  The biggest question I would have is whether or not the table is static after you insert all the values.

Comment: Ah, I see DNNX answered with the same understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd handle it by something like

```
ORDER BY rand()*pow(<probability-field-name>,<n>)
```

for different values of n you will distort the linear probabilities into a simple polynomial. Small values of n (e.g. 0.5) will compress the probabilities to 1 and thus make less probable choices more probable, big values of n (e.g. 2) will do the opposite and further reduce probability of already inprobable values.

Comment: As I understand this pow is POWER function.I have tried it .Each time I get different row but it is going to be same for all of my click .I also want to change selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference in probabilities is too great, you need to add a computed field with a revised weighting that has a more even probability distribution.  How you do that depends on your data and preferred distribution.  One way to do it is to "normalize" the weighting to an integer between 1 and 10 so that the lowest probability is never more than ten times smaller than the highest.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your recent question:

```
SELECT t.Column1, 
       t.Column2,
       (SELECT SUM(Column2) 
        FROM table t2
        WHERE t2.Column1 <= t.Column1) Column3
FROM table t
```

Comment: `t` and `t2` are aliases for table `table`. They reference the same original table.

Comment: oh ok I got it.Thanks ,I am going to try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example how to select one row from the table with taking into account the assigned row weights.

Suppose we have table:

```
CREATE TABLE TableWithWeights(
  Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DataColumn nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  Weight decimal(18, 6) NOT NULL -- Weight column
)
```

Let's fill table with sample data.

```
INSERT INTO TableWithWeights VALUES(1, 'Frequent', 50)
INSERT INTO TableWithWeights VALUES(2, 'Common', 30)
INSERT INTO TableWithWeights VALUES(3, 'Rare', 20)
```

This is the query that returns one random row with taking into account given row weights.

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT tww1.*,     -- Select original table data
     -- Add column with the sum of all weights of previous rows
     (SELECT SUM(tww2.Weight)- tww1.Weight  
      FROM TableWithWeights tww2
      WHERE tww2.id <= tww1.id) as SumOfWeightsOfPreviousRows
    FROM TableWithWeights tww1) as tww,
    -- Add column with random number within the range [0, SumOfWeights)
    (SELECT RAND()* sum(weight) as rnd    
     FROM TableWithWeights) r 
WHERE  
         (tww.SumOfWeightsOfPreviousRows <= r.rnd) 
     and ( r.rnd < tww.SumOfWeightsOfPreviousRows + tww.Weight)
```

To check query results we can run it for 100 times.

```
DECLARE @count as int;
SET @count = 0;
WHILE ( @count < 100)
BEGIN
    -- This is the query that returns one random row with
    -- taking into account given row weights
    SELECT * FROM
       (SELECT tww1.*,     -- Select original table data
         -- Add column with the sum of all weights of previous rows
         (SELECT SUM(tww2.Weight)- tww1.Weight  
          FROM TableWithWeights tww2
          WHERE tww2.id <= tww1.id) as SumOfWeightsOfPreviousRows
        FROM TableWithWeights tww1) as tww,
       -- Add column with random number within the range [0, SumOfWeights)
       (SELECT RAND()* sum(weight) as rnd    
        FROM TableWithWeights) r 
    WHERE  
         (tww.SumOfWeightsOfPreviousRows <= r.rnd) 
     and ( r.rnd < tww.SumOfWeightsOfPreviousRows + tww.Weight) 

    -- Increase counter
    SET @count += 1
END
```

PS The query was tested on SQL Server 2008 R2. And of course the query can be optimized (it's easy to do if you get the idea)